# Fetching data from database(React.js)

Tags: reactjs

In my app, some components use different categories of data(clothes, shoes etc.).
Is it better to fetch data from database once and put it to storage? Or i should let every single component fetch data directly from database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for Redux (an implementation of flux). Redux gives you a global state to work with that you can connect components into. You can make an api call in one component, and if added to state (using actions + reducers), you can update data from a completely different component. They don't even need a parent/child relationship in your component hierarchy.

So yes, you're looking for "storage", in the form of a global state for your entire React app.